# Не работает delete_message aiogram python

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет.
Не могу понять почему БОТ выдаёт ошибку: aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageToDeleteNotFound: Message to delete not found

Делаю регистрацию в БОТе.
Создаю inline кнопки исходя из ID пользователя. Далее по кнопке активирую или удаляю пользователя.
Дабы не повторяться и не запутаться, если поступило много запросов на активацию удаляю сообщение, присланное БОТом с данным пользователя, если сделал какое либо действие на кнопку.
Но после первого запуска БОТа, первая отработка активации или удаления проходит на ура и сообщение с данными удаляется, а вот при следующем действии сообщение не удаляется и выдаёт ошибку которая выше. Код вот:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'active_user')
    async def call_menu_admin_user_seach(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        tupl_users = funct_sql.no_active_user_seach()
        if bool(tupl_users) == False:
            await callback.message.answer('✅В БД нет не активированных пользователей')
            await callback.answer()
        else:
            spisok_id = dict()
            spisok_id.clear()
            for x in tupl_users:
                keyboard_user_action = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                activation_user = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅Активировать',
                                                             callback_data=f'active_{x[2]}')
                delete_user = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌Удалить',
                                                         callback_data=f'delete_{x[2]}')
                keyboard_user_action.add(activation_user, delete_user)

                msg_action = await callback.message.answer(f'ФИО: {x[0]}\n'
                                                           f'Роль: {x[1]}\n'
                                                           f'ID: {x[2]}', reply_markup=keyboard_user_action)
                id_msg = msg_action.message_id
                spisok_id[id_msg] = x[2]
                await callback.answer()
        
        @dp.callback_query_handler()
        async def del_or_activ(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
            for key, value in spisok_id.items():
                if callback.data == f'active_{value}':
                    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, message_id=key)
                    funct_sql.active_user_in_db(value)
                    await callback.message.answer(f'✅Пользователь {value} - Активирован!')
                    await bot.send_message(value, f'✅Ваш аккаунт активирован в системе\n'
                                                  f'Введите команды ❗️/start❗️ или ❗️/menu❗️, '
                                                  f'чтобы начать работу с БОТом!')
                    await callback.answer()
                if callback.data == f'delete_{value}':
                    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, message_id=key)
                    funct_sql.delete_user_in_db(value)
                    await callback.message.answer(f'❌Пользователь {value} - Удалён!')
                    await bot.send_message(value, f'❌Ваш аккаунт удалён из системы❌\n'
                                                  f'Обратитесь к Администратору БОТа.')
                    await callback.answer()
```

Причём если закомментировать строку:

```
await bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, message_id=key)
```

всё работает без проблем по значение value из словаря spisok_id.

П.С. Есть подозрение, что надо передать словарь из хендлера в хендлер через FSM, но пока не знаю как... Прошу пнуть в верном направлении.

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался, действительно надо было передавать словарь через машину состояний FSM....